# Why am I getting "Cannot convert null to 'ScheduleType' because it is a non-nullable value type" here?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-pages

I understand what the error means, but not in this context. VS's Error List is pointing to the 1st line below and saying

> Cannot convert null to 'ScheduleType' because it is a non-nullable
>   value type

```
@using MyNamespace.ViewModels.Workflow.Schedule

@model ScheduleType

<div class="form-group">
    <div id="scheduleTypeRadio">
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            @foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(Model.GetType()).Cast<ScheduleType>())
            {
                <label class="btn btn-primary @if(Model == value) { <text>active</text> }">
                    @Html.RadioButton("scheduleType", value, new { onchange = "if($(this).prop('checked') === true) $(this).closest('form').submit();" })
                    @if (value == ScheduleType.OnDemand && ((bool?)ViewData["immediateMode"]) == true)
                    {
                        @:Immediate
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => value)
                    }
                </label>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So the exact line is

```
@using MyNamespace.ViewModels.Workflow.Schedule
```

and how does that line use `ScheduleType` as if it's nullable? Makes no sense.

Comment: Maybe there is some `static` code in `MyNamespace.ViewModels.Workflow.Schedule` namespace that do the bad things?

Comment: Just to confirm, this is a compiler error, not a runtime error? What happens if you get rid of `@using` and use the full namespace for `ScheduleType`? I'm trying to understand if, for some odd reason, it's indicating the error on the wrong line.

Answer (score 0):

looks like your model is value type (enum) -  `@model ScheduleType`

and you use it to get the possible values -`Enum.GetValues(Model.GetType())`

i think you might want to use a object type of model, and also when getting the list of possible enum values, try: `Enum.GetValues(typeof(ScheduleType))`

Comment: did not get your point - what did not work? changing to real object type instead of value type? the problem most likely lies at using value type instead of object type, so it throws error when trying to convert